# Can I use Git in the Node.js console? If yes, how to install?

Tags: node.js, windows, git

Is it possible to set so

```
mpm install nodegit
```

and then just write Git commands in the Node.js console? To use one console for Git and Gulp it will be more convenient to me ..

Comment: Does adding the `-g` flag work? If not, you can run node from the git bash

Comment: What's the point of installing something with the expectation that it works the same as the command-line tool you already have? The idea behind `nodegit` is to provide a *programmatic* interface to git, not a command-line one. Also what "Node.js console" are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

[Nodegit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodegit) is a library to use in an app you're writing or to be installed alongside another app or service that uses it. It's not meant to be a way to install your personal git command line tool. Download [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and install it. By default it installs its own git bash prompt (which is probably what you're complaining about) but during install there is a screen that allows you to use git in the normal Windows command prompt or PowerShell.

[image]

The screen above defaults to "Use Git Bash only". Change it to "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt" and it will work like you want in the same shell that you're running node and npm in.